# OpenGL code slow on one computer (but not on others)

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I have a shader that is currently doing some raytracing. The shader used to take the scene information as uniforms to render the scene but this proved to be way too limited so we switched to using SSBOs (shader storage buffer objects). The code works perfectly on two computers, but another computer is rendering it very slowly. The video card for that computer is a radeon HD 6950. The video cards that are rendering it correctly are a GTX 570 and a radeon HD 7970. The scene is shown correctly on the three computers but the radeon HD 6950 is rendering it very slowly (1 FPS when we are rotating around the scene). We thought it was a openGL version problem but it doesn't seem to be the case since we updated the drivers and it still doesn't work. Any idea where the problem might be?

Comment: Just to eliminate the usual suspects: In which way did you perform the driver update? The only way to get proper OpenGL support on Windows is to download the drivers directly from the vendor's website and install those. The drivers shipping with and updated by Windows built-in methods lack modern OpenGL support.

Comment: Drivers were downloaded on the nvidia/ati website. OpenGL version indicates support for at least 4.3 (which is the version in which SSBOs were added to openGL) in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

1. You could be falling off the fast path on that particular card. Some aspect of your rendering may not be implemented as efficiently on the lower-end card, for example.
2. You may be hitting the VRAM limit on the 6950, but not on the other 2 cards and OpenGL is essentially thrashing, swapping things out to main memory and back
3. You may have triggered software rendering on that card. There may be some specific OpenGL feature you're using that's only implemented in software for the 6950, but is hardware accelerated on the other cards.

You don't say which OS you're working with, so I'm not sure what to tell you about debugging the problem. On MacOS you can use OpenGL Profiler to see if it's falling back to software and use OpenGL Driver Monitor to see if it's paging out. On iOS you can use Xcode's OpenGL profiling instrument for both of those. I'm not sure on Windows or Linux as I don't have experience with them.

Comment: "Some aspect of your rendering may not be supported as well", that is not true. The computer can only create an OpenGL Context to x selected version, if the computer supports all the core functions of that version.

Comment: That was poorly phrased on my part. What I meant was that the driver for one card may implement a feature less efficiently than the driver for another card. For example, if I recall correctly (and it's possible that I don't!), the early ATI cards didn't support 32-bit blending, but the Nvidia ones did. (Or maybe it was the reverse.) Later cards supported it, so you could end up in a situation where you had to support both, but you needed to emulate it on older cards, which made it slower.

Comment: That makes more sense, you should edit the answer and write that instead.

Comment: I'm on windows. Is there anyway to see if it falls back to software on that OS?

Comment: @Djeezus: You can look at the GL_RENDERER string reported by glGetString. Usually (but not mandatory) it gets reported there, if you fell back to SW rasterization.